# Building buffer arrays in arduino with elements of variable length via Serial

Tags: arrays, arduino

I wrote a mix of python code and arduino code to make this work. I am sending an array of numbers ranging from 0-65353 as strings from python via bluetooth (bluetoothsocket(RFCOMM)). They are received character by character in the arduino and read into an array which will convert the char array into the single original int.  I am wondering if this should be the way to go.  The ints should ideally be between 0-65353.

```
# define ledPinr 4



void setup() {
pinMode(ledPinr, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(ledPinr, LOW);
Serial.begin(115200);
Serial.setTimeout(10000);   // for now, not too important
}

void loop() {
// Read serial input:
char val[5]; // 


if (Serial.available()){
digitalWrite(ledPinr, LOW);


Serial.readBytesUntil(',', val, 5);  



unsigned int num = atol(val);
}
if (Serial.available()==0){
digitalWrite(ledPinr, HIGH);
}
}
```

My issue with this method is that to make it work I have to initially pad the ints I'm sending with 0's so they are all length 5, eg: ints2send=['00001','65353','01000'].  Then they are set into a char array in arduino, eg: {'0','0','0','0','1'} and atol ignores the leading 0's when converting to int 1. Being kind of a newcomer to arduino **I'm wondering if there is a way to read the chars into an array of variable length?**,eg: {'1'},{'6','5','3','5','3'}.  **Or if there is a way to initialize a char array that will not give an error if I send just the value with no padding?**  Or I'm wondering if it will even be worth it to fix this problem, but I'm just curious if there's something I can learn from improving this code.  I realize that I am really ignoring the Serial.readBytesUntil parameter that stops reading when the ',' is found, but ideally I'd like to pause the sending at some point so I dont see making ints2send=['00012,00034'] as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading your buffer, you way want to check if the character is a digit. Then you would like to convert it as an integer or so.

First thing to know is that `int` on arduino is coded on two bytes, and it is **signed**. This means its value is between -2^15=-32768 and 2^15 - 1=32767. https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/int/ 
If you would like to store a value between 0 and 65535(2^16), you should use an `unsigned int`. https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/unsignedint/

Then you can read this way:

```
unsigned char byte;
unsigned int value = 0;
while (Serial.available() > 0) {
  // read the incoming byte:
  byte = Serial.read();

  //stop if you read a comma
  if (byte == ',')
    break;
  //update the value if you read a digit
  if (byte >= '0' && byte <= '9')
    value = 10 * value + (byte - '0');
}
```

The computation of the value uses the fact that each time you read another digit, it means you shift the numbers you previously read. This means multiplying by 10 in base 10. Then to get the value of the character, you just have tu substract the ASCII value of `0`, since, fortunately, digits are coded in the right order.

Note that this solution works whatever the length of the number in the string, provided you don't overflow the maximum `unsigned int` value.

Comment: In this case though, wouldn't I have to send the arduino a single string? something like ['1,65535,...'] for the "if byte==;" to break the while loop .

Comment: Well, you have to adapt the code to your particular case. However, don't forget that the code is running in a loop : `void loop { … }`. You can even remove the while loop, declare the variables in `setup`. Then when you get a `,` you store the value, do whatever you would like to do with it, etc. It depends on how you would like to handle your parsing and what you would like to do with it.